# DTrace script never reports write syscalls

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mountain-lion, system-calls, dtrace

I'm using the following DTrace script to follow the read and write syscalls of bash:

```
syscall::write:entry,
syscall::read:entry
/execname == "bash"/
{

}
```

It successfully matches 2 probes, but no matter what I type, I only see the read calls. No write calls are ver reported. I was expecting to get write calls when the shell echos back to screen.

Is the script wrong, or am I under the wrong assumptions of how bash works?

I'm running under OSX Mountain Lion

Comment: Do you see them if you define them separately w/o using comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a wildcard after "write".  This will list the matching probes:

```
sudo dtrace -l -n 'syscall::write*:entry'
```

And this will probably get you the output you expect:

```
syscall::write*:entry,
syscall::read*:entry
/execname == "bash"/
{

}
```

The call being used is probably `write_nocancel`.

Comment: There's not much out there. Apple has a release note titled [Symbol Variants: Why Those Dollar Signs?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Darwin/SymbolVariantsRelNotes/) the mentions symbol variants with a `$NOCANCEL` suffix. Those are the library cover functions, but the syscalls they wrap actually have a `_nocancel` suffix. All it says about them, though, is "used internally". I believe they're related to [pthread cancellation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/pthread_setcanceltype.3.html).

Comment: Thanks! I was amazed I couldn't find almost any mention on google.